# Fetching data from firebase to DateTimeRange using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I got a package for a booking calendar and its been challenging for me. I need to parse data from firebase and convert to a list.
Here's the code

```
final bookings = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bookings');

///This is how can you get the reference to your data from the collection, 
  ///and serialize the data with the help of the Firestore [withConverter].
  /// This function would be in your repository.
  CollectionReference<SportBooking> getBookingStream({required String placeId}) {
    return bookings.doc(placeId).collection('bookings').withConverter<SportBooking>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => SportBooking.fromJson(snapshots.data()!),
          toFirestore: (snapshots, _) => snapshots.toJson(),
        );
  }

  ///How you actually get the stream of data from Firestore with the help of the previous function
  ///note that this query filters are for my data structure, you need to adjust it to your solution.

/// When I put a range with no data in the DB I get the empty converted list but with a range that has data then I receive a stackoverflow error. So I know that the data is read but can't parse it to my DateTimeRange List

  Stream<dynamic>? getBookingStreamFirebase(
    {required DateTime end, required DateTime start}) {
       return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bookings').withConverter<SportBooking>(
        fromFirestore:  (snapshots, _) => SportBooking.fromJson(snapshots.data()!),
          toFirestore: (snapshots, _) => snapshots.toJson(),
        ).where('bookingStart', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now()
                        .where('bookingStart', isLessThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 50))).snapshots();
  }

  // Stream<List<SportBooking>> get

  ///After you fetched the data from firestore, we only need to have a list of datetimes from the bookings:
  List<DateTimeRange> convertStreamResultFirebase(
    {required dynamic streamResult}) {

    
    

    ///this snapshot should be converted to List<DateTimeRange>
    // final data = snapshot.requireData; **//THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT LINE** and I dont seem to understand this part as well


    ///here you can parse the streamresult and convert to [List<DateTimeRange>]
    ///Note that this is dynamic, so you need to know what properties are available on your result, in our case the [SportBooking] has bookingStart and bookingEnd property
      List<DateTimeRange> converted = []
      for (var i = 0; i < data.size; i++) {
        final item = data.docs[i].data();
        converted.add(DateTimeRange(start: (item.bookingStart!), end: (item.bookingEnd!)));
        }
    return converted;
  }
```

Here's how my data is stored in firestore.
The streamResult should follow this structure.

[image: Here's how my data is stored in firestore]

What may be causing this error?

Comment: Is there something in that code that's not working? What troubleshooting have you done? Please update and clarify the question.

Comment: I'm having trouble with getting the booking stream from firebase. That's where the problem originates, when I call data bookingStart greater or equal to dates not in my DB I get an empty List which is okay but when I put the datetime range available in my DB it keeps bringing the Stack Overflow error on my widget. @Jay

Comment: There are many places where the code could go wrong and either not throw any error or crash. It's generally accepted practice to troubleshoot code before posting it so you can write a clear question. For example, what if the end date is before the start date?. Now, we don't *know* that's the case as we don't really know what your vars are resolving to. Please do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Then update your question with your findings.

Comment: I have tried giving more info to my problem now. I hope its better explained now. @Jay

Comment: From Flutter's console, where the Stackoverflow error is reporting, check the exact file and line of code from where the error starts. I guess it is this file. Highlight which code line the error originates from. And also follow up the stacktrace (other files you created and their lines) that are part of it. This should give insights to how to solve the problem.

Comment: And as @Jay rightly said, it is difficult to reproduce your setup and difficult to think of what could be the solution with the way you presented your question. Try on your own to troubleshoot and possibly solve and take time to develop a good question post. This will help others help you.

Comment: I understood both of you, added breakpoints and found out the problem was on my